# What are the smallest numbers $n$ such that $\dfrac{d(n)}{\ln(n)} \geq k$ where $d(n) = \sigma_0(n)$ is the number-of-divisors function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, divisibility, divisor-sum

I have calculated $\dfrac{d(n)}{\ln(n)}$ on a few highly composite numbers up to 5040.

Here is what I got:

$\dfrac{d(120)}{\ln(120)} = 3.3420423$

$\dfrac{d(360)}{\ln(360)} = 4.0773999$

$\dfrac{d(1260)}{\ln(1260)} = 5.0428170$

$\dfrac{d(2520)}{\ln(2520)} = 6.12869166$

$\dfrac{d(5040)}{\ln(5040)} = 7.03798995$

So we have:

$k=3 : n=120$

$k=4 : n=360$

$k=5 : n=1260$

$k=6 : n=2520$

$k=7 : n=5040$

Notice how, except for $1260$, all of them are superior highly composite numbers!

Could someone calculate the next few $n$ up to $k=12$ ?

Comment: It is more useful to recognize that these are all highly composite numbers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number ) and that the argument at the cited page shows that they must be.

Comment: Which means that you may do this yourself by restricting to numbers with non-increasing exponents. Take a primorial $N$ with largest prime factor $P.$ write a multiple loop for the exponents in $2^{e_2} 3^{e_3} 5^{e_5} \cdots P^{e_P},$ with $e_2 \geq e_3 \geq \cdots.$ Easy to find your function for each of these, also easy to ensure they are no larger than $N.$ No need to actually multiply anything out, not required at first.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be the primes in the usual order: $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, \dots$  Let $f:\mathrm{Z} \rightarrow \mathrm{Z}: n \mapsto \frac{d(n)}{\ln n}$ be the function of interest.  Let $n$ be an integer with factorization $n = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{e_i}$.  Then we compute directly that $d(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (e_i+1)$ and $\ln(n) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty e_i \ln p_i$.

Imagine a sequence of exponents $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ (where only a finite number of exponents are nonzero so that the corresponding $n$ is finite).  We may permute these $e_i$ without changing the number of divisors of the corresponding $n$s.  To maximize $f$ over these corresponding $n$s we must minimize $\ln n$, which means we must assign the largest of the $e_i$ to the first several primes, then the next largest $e_i$, and so on, so that the sequence of exponents is nonincreasing.  Therefore, the only numbers that can appear in the desired list of record values of $f$ have nonincreasing sequences of exponents in their prime decompositions.

To organize the search, sequentially fix $s$ and for each value of $s$, enumerate all nonincreasing sequences of exponents summing to $s$, i.e., such that $s = \sum_{i=1}^\infty e_i$.  Then evaluate $f$ applied to each of these values and accumulate the records for each unit interval.  (That is, for each unit interval, track the least integer which produced a value in that interval.)  Applying this method, we get the sequence continuation (with corresponding approximate values of $f$ shown in parentheses):
$$..., 15120 (8.313), 27720 (9.384), 55440 (10.986), 83160 (11.299), 110880 (12.397), ... $$

$f(55440) = 10.986$ suggests, that there are larger numbers than those on our list with smaller values of $f$ in their unit intervals.  This is true, but not interesting.  The sequence of powers of $2$ produce ever decreasing values.  For instance $1.503 \dot{=} f(2^{14}) < f(2^{13}) < f(2^{12}) < \dots$

Answer (score 0):

If we add the restriction $k< \frac{d(n)}{ln(n)} < k+1$ then:

k=8  n=15120

k=9  n=27720

k=10 n=55440

k=11 n=83160

k=12 n=110880

k=13 n=166320

k=14 n=277200

k=15 n=332640

k=16 n=554400

k=17 n=720720

k=18 n=1081080

k=20 n= 1441440

It seems there are no highly composite number (HCN) with $19< \frac{d(n)}{ln(n)} < 20$

but $19<\frac{d(1801800)}{ln(1801800)}<20$,

so if we consider the restriction $k< \frac{d(n)}{ln(n)} < k+1$

it's false n must be a HCN.

Comment: This fact appears again with k=24

Comment: Since HCN is an abbreviation not used in the Question itself, it would help Readers if you spell out at least once what you mean by this, presumably "highly composite number".

Comment: @hardmath, I followed your suggestion. Thank you.